# How can I insert messages after rows?

Tags: html, ajax, json

I have this sample bit of code and I wanted to know how I can go about numbering all these rows so that way when I click on the read button, it opens a box directly below the row associated with it and displays the message. I don't really know how I can identify the rows and make the message appear after the correct one.

```
var email;
$.getJSON("list.js", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    email = data;
    // data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such

    var table = document.getElementById("start");

    for( var i = 0; i<email.length; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<button id="' + email[i].ID + '">Read</button>';
        cell2.innerHTML = email[i].ID;
        cell3.innerHTML = email[i].Time;
        cell4.innerHTML = email[i].Subject;
    }

});
```

This is what I have so far, I was told that I can call the button by the id that I am assigning to it and call the parent of the parent and insert a row after it but I can't seem to get it in right. Any suggestions?

Well, for the most part, I took your suggestions and I was able to get it to work a bit better but I am having a problem.

```
var email;
$.getJSON("list.js", function(data) {
console.log(data);
email = data;
// data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such

var table = document.getElementById("start");

for( var i = 0; i<email.length; i++)
{
var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = '<button id="' + email[i].ID + '" onclick="getmessage(this.id)">Read</button>';
cell2.innerHTML = email[i].ID;
cell3.innerHTML = email[i].Time;
cell4.innerHTML = email[i].Subject;
}
 });

 var x;
 function getmessage(x)
{
var a = $("#" + x).parent().parent();
//debugger;
$.getJSON(x + ".js", function(data) {
debugger;
a.after('<tr><td colSpan = 4>' + x + ".js" + '</td></tr>');
})
};


 /*var x;
 function getmessage(x)
{
var a = $("#" + x).parent().parent();
a.after('<tr><td colSpan = 4>' + x + ".js" + '</td></tr>');
}   
*/
```

This is what I have so far but for some reason, when I post this code and test it, only the last element of my list appears afterwards. I take off the .getJSON part and they all make messages after the row where the button was pressed but when I include it, I notice that all the files are getting called correctly but only the last row posts a message. What could be wrong with the code?

UPDATE: I just realized that it wasn't accepting files with uppercase letters. Why is that?

Comment: can you create fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var email;
$.getJSON("list.js", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    email = data;
    // data is a JavaScript object now. Handle it as such

    var table = document.getElementById("start");

    for( var i = 0; i<email.length; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

        cell1.innerHTML = '<button class="readbutton" data-email="' + email[i].ID + '">Read</button>';
        cell2.innerHTML = email[i].ID;
        cell3.innerHTML = email[i].Time;
        cell4.innerHTML = email[i].Subject;
        var row2 = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
        $(cell4).attr("colspan",3); 
        $(cell4).attr("dispaly","none");
        $(cell4).attr("id",email[i].ID+"_msg");
        cell4.innerHTML = email[i].message;
    }

});
and 
some where in your script
$(".readbutton").click(function(){
    $($(this).data("email")+"_msg").toggle();
});
```